# How do I fetch the response of an API URL using elevated privileges inside my web method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, sharepoint-2010

We have a search API with the URL of the form `webURL + "/_api/search/query?querytext='" + query + "'";` whose response is required to generate the contents on a page. This URL is accessible directly via AJAX, but the URL is only accessible by admin users. In order for regular users to use the search feature, the workaround was to have a call to a web method which inturn calls the API's URL using elevated privileges.

We have the code as below, but we're unsure how to open the API's URL using the elevated privileges and return the response.

```
public string GetSearchListItems(string query)
{
    var superUser = SPContext.Current.Web.AllUsers[@"SHAREPOINT\SYSTEM"];
    var superToken = superUser.UserToken;
    var webURL = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;
    using (var site = new SPSite(webURL, superToken))
    {
        string searchURL = webURL + "/_api/search/query?querytext='" + query + "'" +"&rowlimit=4&sortlist='ViewsLifeTime:descending'";

        using (var elevatedWeb = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            // code to open searchURL using elevated privileges and return the response of searchURL
        }
    }
}
```

We tried the following in place of the comment above:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string response = client.DownloadString(searchURL);
return response;
```

... but this results in a 401 (Unautorized) exception.

How do we integrate the elevated privileges (the SharePoint\System account) into opening the search API's URL?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping the code you commented in the RunWithElevatedPrivileges() delegate.

e.g

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string response = client.DownloadString(searchURL);
return response;
});
```

Comment: Tried this; still gives 401.